# Beautifulsoup Python: Goibibo hotel rates

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract hotel rates from Goibibo.
url : https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/hotels-in-ahmedabad-ct/
I'm using the following code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
# target URL to scrape
url = ""
# headers
headers = {
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"
            }
        
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(data)


cards_data = data.find_all('div', attrs={'class', 'HotelCardstyles__HotelCardInfoWrapperDiv-sc-1s80tyk-7 iLLynP'})
print('Total Number of Cards Found:', len(cards_data)

for card in cards_data:
    hotel_name = card.find('a')
    room_price = card.find('p', attrs={'class': 'HotelCardstyles__CurrentPrice-sc-1s80tyk-28 inUyrJ'})
    print(hotel_name.text, room_price.text)
```

The problem I have is, the given url picks up default values of date of booking.

When I change the date of booking to desired values, and change search parameters accordingly the output turns to 0 cards found.

url with updated dates : [https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/find-hotels-in-Jaipur/4278754392716898526/4278754392716898526/%7B%22ci%22:%2220210520%22,%22co%22:%2220210521%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22%7D/?{%22filter%22:{}}&sec=dom&cc=IN](https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/find-hotels-in-Jaipur/4278754392716898526/4278754392716898526/%7B%22ci%22:%2220210520%22,%22co%22:%2220210521%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22%7D/?%7B%22filter%22:%7B%7D%7D&sec=dom&cc=IN)

I am not able to understand what changes and what to change in order to get those cards. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When the date filters are changed the actual content is served, differently. You can see it by opening the "Network tab" of the "Google Chrome developer tools" (or the equivalent of your browser).

In this particular example you provided, the data comes in JSON form from this URL:

https://hermes.goibibo.com/hotels/v12/search/data/v3/4278754392716898526/20210520/20210521/1-2-0?s=popularity&cur=INR&tmz=-120

Comment: Any suggestions on how to work with the lower URL ?
Is this also a case where Selenium would be required ?

Comment: I´d first try to understand how to build this URLs. To do so, you can either debug the JS or just experiment with different search parameters to see how it changes. If that doesn´t work, then I´d try selenium (that I'm guessing it will work but it's heavier in usage resources).